# replace array element as id tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The element in an array is suppose id tag for the following code but it doesn't seems to work over here.
Every time highlight function is called it should remove the current class from previous id tag and the class current should be pointed to next array element that act as id tag.

**HTML CODE**

```
<p class="current" id="one">Point 1</p>
<p id="two">Point 2</p>
<p id="three">Point 3</p>
<p id="four">Point 4</p>
<p id="five">Point 5</p>
<p id="six">Point 6</p>
<p id="seven">Point 7</p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
//The array element is suppose to be the next id tag  and it should keep replacing as the function is called.
function highlight() {
    var point = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];

    var i = 0;

    $("#point[i]").removeClass("current"); //#point[i] doesn't seems to replace this thing

    i++
    if (i > 6) {
        i = 0;
    }

    $("#point[i]").addClass("current");

}
setTimeout(highlight, 5000);
```

Comment: There is no iteration in your code!

Comment: I want the array element as an id but it is not happening

Comment: Then it's `$("#" + point[i])`

Comment: You need to make `i` a global variable and move its initialization outside of the function or it will always be reinitialized to 0 when you enter the `highlight` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not simply do this?

```
(function highlight() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $current = $("p.current").removeClass("current");
        var $next = $current.next().length && $current.next() || $current.siblings().first();
        $next.addClass("current");
        highlight();
    }, 1000);
}());
```

```js
(function highlight() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $current = $("p.current").removeClass("current");
        var $next = $current.next().length && $current.next() || $current.siblings().first();
        $next.addClass("current");
        highlight();
    }, 1000);
}())
```

```css
.current {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="current" id="one">Point 1</p>
  <p id="two">Point 2</p>
  <p id="three">Point 3</p>
  <p id="four">Point 4</p>
  <p id="five">Point 5</p>
  <p id="six">Point 6</p>
  <p id="seven">Point 7</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @lshettyl's suggest, I also change to setInterval() to replay every time gap:

```js
var i = 0;

function highlight() {
  var point = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
  $("#" + point[i]).removeClass("current"); //#point[i] doesn't seems to replace this thing

  i++
  if (i > 6) {
    i = 0;
  }
  $("#" + point[i]).addClass("current");
}
setInterval(highlight, 1000);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-run highlight and set a reference to the prior element.

```js
var $prior = null;
var point = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
var i = 0;

function highlight() {
  if ($prior != null) $prior.removeClass("current");
  var id = '#' + point[i];
  
  i++;
  if (i > 6) {
    i = 0;
  }

  $(id).addClass("current");
  $prior = $(id);
  setTimeout(highlight, 500);
}

highlight();
```

```css
.current {
  background-color:#aacc66;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="current" id="one">Point 1</p>
<p id="two">Point 2</p>
<p id="three">Point 3</p>
<p id="four">Point 4</p>
<p id="five">Point 5</p>
<p id="six">Point 6</p>
<p id="seven">Point 7</p>
```